# Does getcwd() ignore the size of the buffer and copy it?

Tags: c, linux, getcwd

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    char wd[10];

    if(getcwd(wd,BUFSIZ) == NULL){   //BUFSIZ = 8192
            perror("getcwd");
            exit(1);
    }
    printf("wd = %s\n",wd);
}
```

This C code works well in Ubuntu Linux 20.
The size of buffer wd is 10 but if I print the wd, it can output a string that is over size 10.

I think that the function uses the pointer of wd regardless of size, so it can work well but it can also print dummy string. Is it right?

//Edit :

printf("wd2 = %s\n",wd2); -> printf("wd = %s\n",wd);

Comment: If you lie to the function about how much space is available to store the directory name, weird stuff can happen. Welcome to undefined behavior.

Comment: [man 3 getcwd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) tells you exactly what you need to know. man pages, although cryptic at first, are concise descriptions on exactly how to use individual functions. Why would you `wd[10]` and then `getcwd(wd,BUFSIZ)`??? `10` ain't `8192`...

Comment: Why not `#include <limits.h>` and then `char wd[PATH_MAX];`  and then `if (getcwd (wd, PATH_MAX) == NULL) { ... }`?

Comment: Also, why would you ignore compiler errors? If you `char wd[10];` and try and `printf("wd2 = %s\\n",wd2);` -- how is the compiler to know what `wd2` is? It's not declared, defined or initialized anywhere??? -- and then there is the problem with `\\n` (that is an explicit `'n'` not a newline `'\n'`)

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the code to give question. But I don't change wd2 to wd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lie to `getcwd` about buffer size.

`getcwd` does not magically know the buffer size. Buffers which know their own size is not a C language feature. That's why `getcwd` needs the size parameter!

So, `getcwd` happily writes beyond end of array.

In C, this is Undefined Behavior. Anything can happen, and "anything" includes what you observe here.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, let's get you straightened out:

1. You can't declare `wd` as `char[10]` and then try and read `8192` bytes into it -- won't work,
2. <s>You can't declare `wd` and then try and output `wd2` -- won't work, and your compiler should be screaming errors at you,</s>
3. <s>`\\n` is a literal `"\n"` (two `\\` are a literal `'\'`) not a newline `'\n'`</s>,
4. `#include <limits.h>` and `#define _GNU_SOURCE` to make `PATH_MAX` available -- which is the maximum length a pathname can be on your system (if any) -- then read that many bytes with `getcwd()`.

Putting it altogether, you can do:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE      /* needed for PATH_MAX */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>      /* needed for PATH_MAX */

int main (void) {
    
  char wd[PATH_MAX];    /* define your buffer with size PATH_MAX */ 

  if (getcwd (wd, PATH_MAX) == NULL) {  /* get the same number of bytes */
    perror("getcwd");
    exit(1);
  }
  
  printf ("wd = %s\n", wd);   /* output the results using same variable */
}
```

**Compile**

With the source in `getcwd.c` and ALWAYS compiling with *FULL WARNINGS ENABLED*, you can do:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast -o bin/getcwd getcwd.c
```

(note: I have a `bin` directory in my current directory that I put executables in to keep from cluttering my source directory)

Don't accept code until it compiles without warning. Add `-Werror` to treat warnings as errors so you can't cheat.

**Example Use/Output**

Running the program yields:

```
$ ./bin/getcwd
wd = /home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/debug
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: The situation the OP asks about involves that their code *does* seem to work, contrary to what your (1) predicts.  Your (2) and (3) apparently refer to typos that the OP corrected at about the same time that this answer was posted.  And [`PATH_MAX`'s name is misleading](https://eklitzke.org/path-max-is-tricky).  It is *not* the maximum length of a path on the filesystem, though it might nevertheless be an ok choice for the buffer size in this case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yep, I can only answer the question as it was written at the time of the answer. `1)` only works for paths less than 9-char -- possible, but horribly unlikely and the risk of UB is ever-present. According to GNU, `PATH_MAX` is `"The uniform system limit (if any) for the length of an entire file name"`, so the `if any` weasel words give some wiggle room, but for all practical purposes, it's the best choice. (updated to reflect edit and weasel words)